# using class method as onclick function in custom element

Tags: javascript, function, class, ecmascript-6

Im trying to code a [on/off-switch](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) as a custom element in JavaScript. But I am stuck at setting the onclick method from the element to a defined class method:

```
class ToggleSwitch extends HTMLElement {

pp(f) {
    alert(f);
}

constructor() {
    super();

    this.checked = this.hasAttribute("checked");

    var shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    var label = document.createElement("label");

    span.setAttribute("class", "toggle-span");
    input.setAttribute("class", "toggle-input");
    input.onclick = this.pp("hello");
    label.setAttribute("class", "toggle-label");

    shadow.appendChild(style);
    shadow.appendChild(label);
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.appendChild(span);
}
}

customElements.define("toggle-switch", ToggleSwitch);
```

of course it would be possible to do it like `elem.onclick = () => {...}` but when it comes to large functions, that would be pain. When I select the element and type $0.onclick into the console, it just returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, easier than expected:

```
input.addEventListener("click", () => this.pp("hello"));
```

Comment: Why did you choose this over `input.onclick = () => {...}` ?

Comment: because when it comes to larger onclick-functions that would be awful.

Comment: What part exactly would be aweful? There doesn't seem to be a big difference to me between assigning a large function to a property and passing a large function to another function.